# Rejection odds for an iOS app that parses a 3rd party website

Tags: ios, app-store, submit, appstore-approval

I'm working on an iPhone app that parses HTML from a 3rd party website and displays parsed content in a much more convenient manner. As part of the workflow, the app accepts Credit Card information which is then passed to the 3rd party website, just as in a normal browser.

How high do you think are the odds of my app being rejected by Apple?

Just for clarification, it's not my choice to accept Credit Cards. The website that I'm working with has this step as part of its user interaction. All my app does is wrapping the ugly HTML from each of the steps into a readable, usable, and easily navigable user interface that has mobile look-and-feel.

Comment: I suspect you won't get a firm answer but I'd be worried about guideline 2.17: "Apps that browse the web must use the iOS WebKit framework and WebKit Javascript."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be surprised if Apple rejected your app due to this. However, that said, it's generally not a good idea to do what you've done. The only exception to this is if you (or someone else) intends to religiously maintain and update the app every time any changes are going to be made to the website.

If on the other hand its a one off project to get the app setup, then after than it will be shelved and unsupported I would strongly recommend you reconsider your design.

Either way, provided your code is half decent I'd be very surprised if apple rejected it (it's definitely worth checking Apples guidelines to check you aren't infringing any of their rules).

Hope this helps.

**NOTE:** The part about the credit card info is kind of dodgy territory. The reason I say this is because Amazon recently had issues with Apple since they were taking payments through their Kindle app, yet Apple wasn't receiving its ~30% cut (since payments were being processed through Amazon's own servers etc.). If you're taking payments you may be faced with the same problems - worth baring in mind!

Comment: They actually approved the app which is now on the app store (in Russian): https://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/ticketnow/id571329132

Answer (score 7):

Always remember one thing while making application for Apple. They want customer to be like this,

[image]

## But

your application will definitely fail one day when third party website will change their content. and your customer and Apple's customer will feel like this.

[image]

## Conclusion

Never code something which in long term will break your application or create some very bad user experience.

## And

Apple has rejected Newyork times application for asking credit card detail from customer. So our application has no chance to get passed if we are asking credit card details at any point of time

Comment: I'm not really disagreeing with your advice, Owl, but I will make the comment that it's sad that developers think they're making apps *for Apple*.  Apps are supposed to be made *for customers*.  In this case, I think the poster is pretty clear.  There exists a website that people can use via Mobile Safari, but it's not well designed for a smartphone.  With that in mind, I think the poster's attempt to write an app to parse HTTP and build a better UI is entirely in the users' best interests.  Of course, Apple probably disagrees, but I'm just opining here about the system being flawed.

Comment: @Nate, I do respect your thoughts and I used to think same as you :). But I did close research about the user experience and business model they are using and I think they needs our as a developers support to keep the system clean and simple :). I have seen Android market and it stinks a lot! My friend's accounts just got hacked as he downloaded some app which asked the credit card details! yeah my friend is not that tech savvy so he thought he is giving those details to genuine people. After these type of incidents I think, What Apple does is making strategies which we should believe in :)

Comment: I agree with you about the credit card details.  I think that's exactly the kind of thing Apple should be reviewing.  But, not the bit about scraping 3rd-party content.  If a user gets their credit card info stolen, that's a big deal.  If they use an app that simply parses HTML, and presents a UI that's better designed for a mobile device ... and the HTML content changes, leaving the UI non-functional ... then the user simply loses the app until the developer fixes the issue.  But, they are no worse off than where they started ... where the only way to access a site on their phone was Safari

Comment: ... and anyone with an iPhone should know how painful it can be to browse a website on mobile Safari that's not designed for a small screen.  That's what the poster is trying to avoid.  I'd want that, if the only downside was that once every year or two, the app "breaks" for a week when web content changes.  I have no problem if everyone doesn't agree with me, but there's enough people who do that Apple should be letting the market decide.  I prefer iPhone to Android myself, but not because Apple tells people what they should and shouldn't want in a mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

You don't deliver source code to Apple when you submit your app, so I'm doubtful that they would know that you're **scraping** a website, as opposed to using a normal web services API.  Especially if the website you access is using HTTPS.  I'm guessing the payment part of the website is secured, but maybe not the rest?

Even if the site isn't encrypted with SSL, I haven't seen anything to suggest that Apple reviewers are using network sniffers and inspecting content of HTTP responses and comparing that to what your UI shows.

I don't disagree with other comments about this design (3rd-party website scraping) being brittle, but that wasn't your question, so I won't pile on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Apple will reject your app for parsing a website and presenting some/all of the content in a revised more user-friendly manner.

I do think Apple will reject your app if it asks for credit card payments if the content or service being paid for is used in the app. e.g. if it's a digital magazine subscription you will get rejected. If it's payment for a pair of shoes you will not be rejected.